# Use jq to collect recursive-descent results into a single array

Tags: json, jq, collect, recursive-descent

Is it possible to collect [recursive-descent](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#TypesandValues) results into a single array with `jq`?

Would `flatten` help? Looks so to me, but I just cannot get it working. Take a look how far I am now at https://jqplay.org/s/6bxD-Wq0QE, anyone can make it working?

BTW,

- `.data.search.edges[].node | {name, topics: ..|.topics?}` works, but I want all topics from the same node to be in one array, instead of having same `name` in all different returned results.
- `flatten` alone will give me `Cannot iterate over null`, and
- that's why I'm trying to use `map(select(.? != null))` to filter the `null`s out. However, I'd get `Cannot iterate over null` as well for my `map-select`.

So now it all comes down to how to filter out those `null`s?

**UPDATE:**, by *"collect into a single array"* I meant to get something like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "leumi-leumicard-bank-data-scraper",
    "topics": ["banking", "leumi", "api", "puppeteer", "scraper", "open-api"]
  }
]
```

instead of having same `name` duplicated in all different returned results. Thus recursively descends seems to me to be the option, but I'm open to any solution as long as I can get result like above. Is that possible? Thx.

Comment: post the final expected result

Comment: Please follow the guidelines at stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to collect the non-falsey values:

```
.data.search.edges[].node 
| {name, topics: [.. | .topics? | select(.)]}
```

The result would be:

```
{
  "name": "leumi-leumicard-bank-data-scraper",
  "topics": [
    "banking",
    "leumi",
    "api",
    "puppeteer",
    "scraper",
    "open-api"
  ]
}
{
  "name": "echarts-scrappeteer",
  "topics": []
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you're expecting to get in your results... but it seems like you're trying to get all the repositories and their topics in a flat array. I don't see any reason why you should use recurse here, you're only selecting from one class of objects. Just reference them directly.

```
[.data.search.edges[].node | {name,topic:(.repositoryTopics.nodes[].topic.topics)}]
```

For your particular input produces:

```
[
  {
    "name": "leumi-leumicard-bank-data-scraper",
    "topic": "banking"
  },
  {
    "name": "leumi-leumicard-bank-data-scraper",
    "topic": "leumi"
  },
  {
    "name": "leumi-leumicard-bank-data-scraper",
    "topic": "api"
  },
  {
    "name": "leumi-leumicard-bank-data-scraper",
    "topic": "puppeteer"
  },
  {
    "name": "leumi-leumicard-bank-data-scraper",
    "topic": "scraper"
  },
  {
    "name": "leumi-leumicard-bank-data-scraper",
    "topic": "open-api"
  }
]
```

https://jqplay.org/s/G2inYAJNLS

---

If you wanted to have an array of topics within the nodes instead, just collect them in an array by putting the filter that selects the topics within `[]`.

```
[.data.search.edges[].node | {name,topic:[.repositoryTopics.nodes[].topic.topics]}]
```

```
[
  {
    "name": "leumi-leumicard-bank-data-scraper",
    "topic": [
      "banking",
      "leumi",
      "api",
      "puppeteer",
      "scraper",
      "open-api"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "echarts-scrappeteer",
    "topic": []
  }
]
```

https://jqplay.org/s/0AFneNK89i

Comment: Thanks a lot for your understanding and help Jeff! I edited my OP to make it clear what I want, but noticed afterward that @peak's answer is already giving the correct solution. Thanks again for your help Jeff!